# AES256 encryption only encrypts first 16 characters. C language

Tags: c, encryption, aes

I've been trying to write a password manager in C **for testing purposes** (since I'm a newcomer to C).

I came across [tiny-AES-c](https://www.github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) to encrypt and decrypt a file's contents using aes256s ECB method, however, only the first 16 characters get encrypted.

*I've tried changing the variable BLOCK_LEN but everything stays the same.*

aes.c file:

```c
/*****************************************************************************/
/* Includes:                                                                 */
/*****************************************************************************/
#include <string.h> // CBC mode, for memset
#include "aes.h"

/*****************************************************************************/
/* Defines:                                                                  */
/*****************************************************************************/
// The number of columns comprising a state in AES. This is a constant in AES. Value=4
#define Nb 4

#if defined(AES256) && (AES256 == 1)
    #define Nk 8
    #define Nr 14
#elif defined(AES192) && (AES192 == 1)
    #define Nk 6
    #define Nr 12
#else
    #define Nk 4        // The number of 32 bit words in a key.
    #define Nr 10       // The number of rounds in AES Cipher.
#endif

// jcallan@github points out that declaring Multiply as a function
// reduces code size considerably with the Keil ARM compiler.
// See this link for more information: https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-C/pull/3
#ifndef MULTIPLY_AS_A_FUNCTION
  #define MULTIPLY_AS_A_FUNCTION 0
#endif

/*****************************************************************************/
/* Private variables:                                                        */
/*****************************************************************************/
// state - array holding the intermediate results during decryption.
typedef uint8_t state_t[4][4];

// The lookup-tables are marked const so they can be placed in read-only storage instead of RAM
// The numbers below can be computed dynamically trading ROM for RAM -
// This can be useful in (embedded) bootloader applications, where ROM is often limited.
static const uint8_t sbox[256] = {
  //0     1    2      3     4    5     6     7      8    9     A      B    C     D     E     F
  0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
  0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
  0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
  0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
  0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
  0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
  0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
  0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
  0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
  0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
  0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
  0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08,
  0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a,
  0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e,
  0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf,
  0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16 };

#if (defined(CBC) && CBC == 1) || (defined(ECB) && ECB == 1)
static const uint8_t rsbox[256] = {
  0x52, 0x09, 0x6a, 0xd5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xa5, 0x38, 0xbf, 0x40, 0xa3, 0x9e, 0x81, 0xf3, 0xd7, 0xfb,
  0x7c, 0xe3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9b, 0x2f, 0xff, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8e, 0x43, 0x44, 0xc4, 0xde, 0xe9, 0xcb,
  0x54, 0x7b, 0x94, 0x32, 0xa6, 0xc2, 0x23, 0x3d, 0xee, 0x4c, 0x95, 0x0b, 0x42, 0xfa, 0xc3, 0x4e,
  0x08, 0x2e, 0xa1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xd9, 0x24, 0xb2, 0x76, 0x5b, 0xa2, 0x49, 0x6d, 0x8b, 0xd1, 0x25,
  0x72, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xd4, 0xa4, 0x5c, 0xcc, 0x5d, 0x65, 0xb6, 0x92,
  0x6c, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xfd, 0xed, 0xb9, 0xda, 0x5e, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xa7, 0x8d, 0x9d, 0x84,
  0x90, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x00, 0x8c, 0xbc, 0xd3, 0x0a, 0xf7, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xb8, 0xb3, 0x45, 0x06,
  0xd0, 0x2c, 0x1e, 0x8f, 0xca, 0x3f, 0x0f, 0x02, 0xc1, 0xaf, 0xbd, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8a, 0x6b,
  0x3a, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4f, 0x67, 0xdc, 0xea, 0x97, 0xf2, 0xcf, 0xce, 0xf0, 0xb4, 0xe6, 0x73,
  0x96, 0xac, 0x74, 0x22, 0xe7, 0xad, 0x35, 0x85, 0xe2, 0xf9, 0x37, 0xe8, 0x1c, 0x75, 0xdf, 0x6e,
  0x47, 0xf1, 0x1a, 0x71, 0x1d, 0x29, 0xc5, 0x89, 0x6f, 0xb7, 0x62, 0x0e, 0xaa, 0x18, 0xbe, 0x1b,
  0xfc, 0x56, 0x3e, 0x4b, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9a, 0xdb, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0x78, 0xcd, 0x5a, 0xf4,
  0x1f, 0xdd, 0xa8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xc7, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xec, 0x5f,
  0x60, 0x51, 0x7f, 0xa9, 0x19, 0xb5, 0x4a, 0x0d, 0x2d, 0xe5, 0x7a, 0x9f, 0x93, 0xc9, 0x9c, 0xef,
  0xa0, 0xe0, 0x3b, 0x4d, 0xae, 0x2a, 0xf5, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0xeb, 0xbb, 0x3c, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61,
  0x17, 0x2b, 0x04, 0x7e, 0xba, 0x77, 0xd6, 0x26, 0xe1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0c, 0x7d };
#endif

// The round constant word array, Rcon[i], contains the values given by
// x to the power (i-1) being powers of x (x is denoted as {02}) in the field GF(2^8)
static const uint8_t Rcon[11] = {
  0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36 };

/*
 * Jordan Goulder points out in PR #12 (https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-C/pull/12),
 * that you can remove most of the elements in the Rcon array, because they are unused.
 *
 * From Wikipedia's article on the Rijndael key schedule @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule#Rcon
 *
 * "Only the first some of these constants are actually used – up to rcon[10] for AES-128 (as 11 round keys are needed),
 *  up to rcon[8] for AES-192, up to rcon[7] for AES-256. rcon[0] is not used in AES algorithm."
 */

/*****************************************************************************/
/* Private functions:                                                        */
/*****************************************************************************/
/*
static uint8_t getSBoxValue(uint8_t num)
{
  return sbox[num];
}
*/
#define getSBoxValue(num) (sbox[(num)])

// This function produces Nb(Nr+1) round keys. The round keys are used in each round to decrypt the states.
static void KeyExpansion(uint8_t* RoundKey, const uint8_t* Key)
{
  unsigned i, j, k;
  uint8_t tempa[4]; // Used for the column/row operations

  // The first round key is the key itself.
  for (i = 0; i < Nk; ++i)
  {
    RoundKey[(i * 4) + 0] = Key[(i * 4) + 0];
    RoundKey[(i * 4) + 1] = Key[(i * 4) + 1];
    RoundKey[(i * 4) + 2] = Key[(i * 4) + 2];
    RoundKey[(i * 4) + 3] = Key[(i * 4) + 3];
  }

  // All other round keys are found from the previous round keys.
  for (i = Nk; i < Nb * (Nr + 1); ++i)
  {
    {
      k = (i - 1) * 4;
      tempa[0]=RoundKey[k + 0];
      tempa[1]=RoundKey[k + 1];
      tempa[2]=RoundKey[k + 2];
      tempa[3]=RoundKey[k + 3];

    }

    if (i % Nk == 0)
    {
      // This function shifts the 4 bytes in a word to the left once.
      // [a0,a1,a2,a3] becomes [a1,a2,a3,a0]

      // Function RotWord()
      {
        const uint8_t u8tmp = tempa[0];
        tempa[0] = tempa[1];
        tempa[1] = tempa[2];
        tempa[2] = tempa[3];
        tempa[3] = u8tmp;
      }

      // SubWord() is a function that takes a four-byte input word and
      // applies the S-box to each of the four bytes to produce an output word.

      // Function Subword()
      {
        tempa[0] = getSBoxValue(tempa[0]);
        tempa[1] = getSBoxValue(tempa[1]);
        tempa[2] = getSBoxValue(tempa[2]);
        tempa[3] = getSBoxValue(tempa[3]);
      }

      tempa[0] = tempa[0] ^ Rcon[i/Nk];
    }
#if defined(AES256) && (AES256 == 1)
    if (i % Nk == 4)
    {
      // Function Subword()
      {
        tempa[0] = getSBoxValue(tempa[0]);
        tempa[1] = getSBoxValue(tempa[1]);
        tempa[2] = getSBoxValue(tempa[2]);
        tempa[3] = getSBoxValue(tempa[3]);
      }
    }
#endif
    j = i * 4; k=(i - Nk) * 4;
    RoundKey[j + 0] = RoundKey[k + 0] ^ tempa[0];
    RoundKey[j + 1] = RoundKey[k + 1] ^ tempa[1];
    RoundKey[j + 2] = RoundKey[k + 2] ^ tempa[2];
    RoundKey[j + 3] = RoundKey[k + 3] ^ tempa[3];
  }
}

void AES_init_ctx(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* key)
{
  KeyExpansion(ctx->RoundKey, key);
}
#if (defined(CBC) && (CBC == 1)) || (defined(CTR) && (CTR == 1))
void AES_init_ctx_iv(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* key, const uint8_t* iv)
{
  KeyExpansion(ctx->RoundKey, key);
  memcpy (ctx->Iv, iv, AES_BLOCKLEN);
}
void AES_ctx_set_iv(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* iv)
{
  memcpy (ctx->Iv, iv, AES_BLOCKLEN);
}
#endif

// This function adds the round key to state.
// The round key is added to the state by an XOR function.
static void AddRoundKey(uint8_t round, state_t* state, const uint8_t* RoundKey)
{
  uint8_t i,j;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
      (*state)[i][j] ^= RoundKey[(round * Nb * 4) + (i * Nb) + j];
    }
  }
}

// The SubBytes Function Substitutes the values in the
// state matrix with values in an S-box.
static void SubBytes(state_t* state)
{
  uint8_t i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
      (*state)[j][i] = getSBoxValue((*state)[j][i]);
    }
  }
}

// The ShiftRows() function shifts the rows in the state to the left.
// Each row is shifted with different offset.
// Offset = Row number. So the first row is not shifted.
static void ShiftRows(state_t* state)
{
  uint8_t temp;

  // Rotate first row 1 columns to left
  temp           = (*state)[0][1];
  (*state)[0][1] = (*state)[1][1];
  (*state)[1][1] = (*state)[2][1];
  (*state)[2][1] = (*state)[3][1];
  (*state)[3][1] = temp;

  // Rotate second row 2 columns to left
  temp           = (*state)[0][2];
  (*state)[0][2] = (*state)[2][2];
  (*state)[2][2] = temp;

  temp           = (*state)[1][2];
  (*state)[1][2] = (*state)[3][2];
  (*state)[3][2] = temp;

  // Rotate third row 3 columns to left
  temp           = (*state)[0][3];
  (*state)[0][3] = (*state)[3][3];
  (*state)[3][3] = (*state)[2][3];
  (*state)[2][3] = (*state)[1][3];
  (*state)[1][3] = temp;
}

static uint8_t xtime(uint8_t x)
{
  return ((x<<1) ^ (((x>>7) & 1) * 0x1b));
}

// MixColumns function mixes the columns of the state matrix
static void MixColumns(state_t* state)
{
  uint8_t i;
  uint8_t Tmp, Tm, t;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    t   = (*state)[i][0];
    Tmp = (*state)[i][0] ^ (*state)[i][1] ^ (*state)[i][2] ^ (*state)[i][3] ;
    Tm  = (*state)[i][0] ^ (*state)[i][1] ; Tm = xtime(Tm);  (*state)[i][0] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;
    Tm  = (*state)[i][1] ^ (*state)[i][2] ; Tm = xtime(Tm);  (*state)[i][1] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;
    Tm  = (*state)[i][2] ^ (*state)[i][3] ; Tm = xtime(Tm);  (*state)[i][2] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;
    Tm  = (*state)[i][3] ^ t ;              Tm = xtime(Tm);  (*state)[i][3] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;
  }
}

// Multiply is used to multiply numbers in the field GF(2^8)
// Note: The last call to xtime() is unneeded, but often ends up generating a smaller binary
//       The compiler seems to be able to vectorize the operation better this way.
//       See https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/pull/34
#if MULTIPLY_AS_A_FUNCTION
static uint8_t Multiply(uint8_t x, uint8_t y)
{
  return (((y & 1) * x) ^
       ((y>>1 & 1) * xtime(x)) ^
       ((y>>2 & 1) * xtime(xtime(x))) ^
       ((y>>3 & 1) * xtime(xtime(xtime(x)))) ^
       ((y>>4 & 1) * xtime(xtime(xtime(xtime(x)))))); /* this last call to xtime() can be omitted */
  }
#else
#define Multiply(x, y)                                \
      (  ((y & 1) * x) ^                              \
      ((y>>1 & 1) * xtime(x)) ^                       \
      ((y>>2 & 1) * xtime(xtime(x))) ^                \
      ((y>>3 & 1) * xtime(xtime(xtime(x)))) ^         \
      ((y>>4 & 1) * xtime(xtime(xtime(xtime(x))))))   \

#endif

#if (defined(CBC) && CBC == 1) || (defined(ECB) && ECB == 1)
/*
static uint8_t getSBoxInvert(uint8_t num)
{
  return rsbox[num];
}
*/
#define getSBoxInvert(num) (rsbox[(num)])

// MixColumns function mixes the columns of the state matrix.
// The method used to multiply may be difficult to understand for the inexperienced.
// Please use the references to gain more information.
static void InvMixColumns(state_t* state)
{
  int i;
  uint8_t a, b, c, d;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    a = (*state)[i][0];
    b = (*state)[i][1];
    c = (*state)[i][2];
    d = (*state)[i][3];

    (*state)[i][0] = Multiply(a, 0x0e) ^ Multiply(b, 0x0b) ^ Multiply(c, 0x0d) ^ Multiply(d, 0x09);
    (*state)[i][1] = Multiply(a, 0x09) ^ Multiply(b, 0x0e) ^ Multiply(c, 0x0b) ^ Multiply(d, 0x0d);
    (*state)[i][2] = Multiply(a, 0x0d) ^ Multiply(b, 0x09) ^ Multiply(c, 0x0e) ^ Multiply(d, 0x0b);
    (*state)[i][3] = Multiply(a, 0x0b) ^ Multiply(b, 0x0d) ^ Multiply(c, 0x09) ^ Multiply(d, 0x0e);
  }
}

// The SubBytes Function Substitutes the values in the
// state matrix with values in an S-box.
static void InvSubBytes(state_t* state)
{
  uint8_t i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
      (*state)[j][i] = getSBoxInvert((*state)[j][i]);
    }
  }
}

static void InvShiftRows(state_t* state)
{
  uint8_t temp;

  // Rotate first row 1 columns to right
  temp = (*state)[3][1];
  (*state)[3][1] = (*state)[2][1];
  (*state)[2][1] = (*state)[1][1];
  (*state)[1][1] = (*state)[0][1];
  (*state)[0][1] = temp;

  // Rotate second row 2 columns to right
  temp = (*state)[0][2];
  (*state)[0][2] = (*state)[2][2];
  (*state)[2][2] = temp;

  temp = (*state)[1][2];
  (*state)[1][2] = (*state)[3][2];
  (*state)[3][2] = temp;

  // Rotate third row 3 columns to right
  temp = (*state)[0][3];
  (*state)[0][3] = (*state)[1][3];
  (*state)[1][3] = (*state)[2][3];
  (*state)[2][3] = (*state)[3][3];
  (*state)[3][3] = temp;
}
#endif // #if (defined(CBC) && CBC == 1) || (defined(ECB) && ECB == 1)

// Cipher is the main function that encrypts the PlainText.
static void Cipher(state_t* state, const uint8_t* RoundKey)
{
  uint8_t round = 0;

  // Add the First round key to the state before starting the rounds.
  AddRoundKey(0, state, RoundKey);

  // There will be Nr rounds.
  // The first Nr-1 rounds are identical.
  // These Nr rounds are executed in the loop below.
  // Last one without MixColumns()
  for (round = 1; ; ++round)
  {
    SubBytes(state);
    ShiftRows(state);
    if (round == Nr) {
      break;
    }
    MixColumns(state);
    AddRoundKey(round, state, RoundKey);
  }
  // Add round key to last round
  AddRoundKey(Nr, state, RoundKey);
}

#if (defined(CBC) && CBC == 1) || (defined(ECB) && ECB == 1)
static void InvCipher(state_t* state, const uint8_t* RoundKey)
{
  uint8_t round = 0;

  // Add the First round key to the state before starting the rounds.
  AddRoundKey(Nr, state, RoundKey);

  // There will be Nr rounds.
  // The first Nr-1 rounds are identical.
  // These Nr rounds are executed in the loop below.
  // Last one without InvMixColumn()
  for (round = (Nr - 1); ; --round)
  {
    InvShiftRows(state);
    InvSubBytes(state);
    AddRoundKey(round, state, RoundKey);
    if (round == 0) {
      break;
    }
    InvMixColumns(state);
  }

}
#endif // #if (defined(CBC) && CBC == 1) || (defined(ECB) && ECB == 1)

/*****************************************************************************/
/* Public functions:                                                         */
/*****************************************************************************/
#if defined(ECB) && (ECB == 1)

void AES_ECB_encrypt(const struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf)
{
  // The next function call encrypts the PlainText with the Key using AES algorithm.
  Cipher((state_t*)buf, ctx->RoundKey);
}

void AES_ECB_decrypt(const struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf)
{
  // The next function call decrypts the PlainText with the Key using AES algorithm.
  InvCipher((state_t*)buf, ctx->RoundKey);
}

#endif // #if defined(ECB) && (ECB == 1)

#if defined(CBC) && (CBC == 1)

static void XorWithIv(uint8_t* buf, const uint8_t* Iv)
{
  uint8_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < AES_BLOCKLEN; ++i) // The block in AES is always 128bit no matter the key size
  {
    buf[i] ^= Iv[i];
  }
}

void AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(struct AES_ctx *ctx, uint8_t* buf, size_t length)
{
  size_t i;
  uint8_t *Iv = ctx->Iv;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i += AES_BLOCKLEN)
  {
    XorWithIv(buf, Iv);
    Cipher((state_t*)buf, ctx->RoundKey);
    Iv = buf;
    buf += AES_BLOCKLEN;
  }
  /* store Iv in ctx for next call */
  memcpy(ctx->Iv, Iv, AES_BLOCKLEN);
}

void AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer(struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf, size_t length)
{
  size_t i;
  uint8_t storeNextIv[AES_BLOCKLEN];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i += AES_BLOCKLEN)
  {
    memcpy(storeNextIv, buf, AES_BLOCKLEN);
    InvCipher((state_t*)buf, ctx->RoundKey);
    XorWithIv(buf, ctx->Iv);
    memcpy(ctx->Iv, storeNextIv, AES_BLOCKLEN);
    buf += AES_BLOCKLEN;
  }

}

#endif // #if defined(CBC) && (CBC == 1)

#if defined(CTR) && (CTR == 1)

/* Symmetrical operation: same function for encrypting as for decrypting. Note any IV/nonce should never be reused with the same key */
void AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf, size_t length)
{
  uint8_t buffer[AES_BLOCKLEN];

  size_t i;
  int bi;
  for (i = 0, bi = AES_BLOCKLEN; i < length; ++i, ++bi)
  {
    if (bi == AES_BLOCKLEN) /* we need to regen xor compliment in buffer */
    {

      memcpy(buffer, ctx->Iv, AES_BLOCKLEN);
      Cipher((state_t*)buffer,ctx->RoundKey);

      /* Increment Iv and handle overflow */
      for (bi = (AES_BLOCKLEN - 1); bi >= 0; --bi)
      {
    /* inc will overflow */
        if (ctx->Iv[bi] == 255)
    {
          ctx->Iv[bi] = 0;
          continue;
        }
        ctx->Iv[bi] += 1;
        break;
      }
      bi = 0;
    }

    buf[i] = (buf[i] ^ buffer[bi]);
  }
}

#endif // #if defined(CTR) && (CTR == 1)
```

aes.h:

```c
#ifndef _AES_H_
#define _AES_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#ifndef CBC
  #define CBC 0
#endif

#ifndef ECB
  #define ECB 1
#endif

#ifndef CTR
  #define CTR 0
#endif

//#define AES128 1
//#define AES192 1
#define AES256 1

#define AES_BLOCKLEN 16// 16? Block length in bytes - AES is 128b block only

#if defined(AES256) && (AES256 == 1)
    #define AES_KEYLEN 32
    #define AES_keyExpSize 240
#elif defined(AES192) && (AES192 == 1)
    #define AES_KEYLEN 24
    #define AES_keyExpSize 208
#else
    #define AES_KEYLEN 16   // Key length in bytes
    #define AES_keyExpSize 176
#endif

struct AES_ctx
{
  uint8_t RoundKey[AES_keyExpSize];
#if (defined(CBC) && (CBC == 1)) || (defined(CTR) && (CTR == 1))
  uint8_t Iv[AES_BLOCKLEN];
#endif
};

void AES_init_ctx(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* key);
#if (defined(CBC) && (CBC == 1)) || (defined(CTR) && (CTR == 1))
void AES_init_ctx_iv(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* key, const uint8_t* iv);
void AES_ctx_set_iv(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* iv);
#endif

#if defined(ECB) && (ECB == 1)
// buffer size is exactly AES_BLOCKLEN bytes;
// you need only AES_init_ctx as IV is not used in ECB
// NB: ECB is considered insecure for most uses
void AES_ECB_encrypt(const struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf);
void AES_ECB_decrypt(const struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf);

#endif // #if defined(ECB) && (ECB == !)

#if defined(CBC) && (CBC == 1)
// buffer size MUST be mutile of AES_BLOCKLEN;
// Suggest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7 for padding scheme
// NOTES: you need to set IV in ctx via AES_init_ctx_iv() or AES_ctx_set_iv()
//        no IV should ever be reused with the same key
void AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf, size_t length);
void AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer(struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf, size_t length);

#endif // #if defined(CBC) && (CBC == 1)

#if defined(CTR) && (CTR == 1)

// Same function for encrypting as for decrypting.
// IV is incremented for every block, and used after encryption as XOR-compliment for output
// Suggesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7 for padding scheme
// NOTES: you need to set IV in ctx with AES_init_ctx_iv() or AES_ctx_set_iv()
//        no IV should ever be reused with the same key
void AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf, size_t length);

#endif // #if defined(CTR) && (CTR == 1)

#endif // _AES_H_
```

main.c:

```c
#include "aes.h"
uint8_t * username;
uint8_t * password;
int main(){
    username = malloc(240);
    password = malloc(240);
    uint8_t key[32] =  {0};
    struct AES_ctx ctx;
    AES_init_ctx(&ctx, key);

    printf("Enter username: ");
    fgets(username, 50, stdin);
    printf("Enter password: ");
    fgets(password, 50, stdin);

    AES_ECB_encrypt(&ctx, username);
    AES_ECB_encrypt(&ctx, password);
    printf("Username: [%s]\n", username);
    printf("Password: [%s]\n", password);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter username: thisismyusername123
Enter password: thisismypassword123
Username: [îsÌX#çyr¬ñSëäÒ123]
Password: [Øy%Ýá]2 ÐBw©¬T123]
```

Notice that the final "123" remains.
Thanks!

Comment: The README of the library you are using clearly states that "ECB mode is considered unsafe for most uses and is not implemented in streaming mode. If you need this mode, call the function for every block of 16 bytes you need encrypted. See wikipedia's article on ECB for more details."

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` format specifier in the `printf` function call requires a null-terminated string. It will continue printing until it finds such a null terminator.

The encrypted buffer may not be null terminated. In that case, it will continue printing everything else it finds in memory until it finds such a null terminator. That is one possible reason why your program is printing parts of the [plaintext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintext).

However, with the sample input `thisismyusername123`, the problem is not the `printf` function call, but rather the following problem:

The function `AES_ECB_encrypt` assumes that the buffer is `AES_BLOCKLEN` bytes long (which is 16 bytes). Therefore, if your unencrypted data is larger than this, you will have to call the function multiple times, once for every `AES_BLOCKLEN` bytes of plaintext. Alternatively, you can use the function `AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer` instead, which allows you to specify the total buffer size, so you can encrypt all data at once. This also has the advantage that [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)) is more secure than [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB)).

Note that in both cases, the total buffer size must be a multiple of `AES_BLOCKLEN` bytes. Therefore, you should ensure that this is the case by adding padding, for example by adding bytes containing the value `0` after your actual string. If you want the padding to be more cryptographically secure, the documentation of your library recommends that you use [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) for padding.

Since you are only calling `AES_ECB_encrypt` once, it will only encrypt the first 16 bytes of the string, so it will only encrypt `thisismyusername` and it won't encrypt `123`. Therefore, as described above, you must either call this function several times (once for every block of plaintext) or you must use the function `AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer` instead. I recommend that you use `AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer`, as it is more cryptographically secure.

You should not attempt to change the block size to a different value than 16 bytes, as the AES256 algorithm requires a block size of exactly 16 bytes (which is 256 bits).

Also, as a side note, you probably want to remove the newline character from `username` and `password` before encrypting it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471) for the best ways to do this.